# RxJava NetworkOnMainThreadException while subscribing

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I'm trying to call API and add data to my LiveData, but after I subscribe, I get MainThreadException in OnError. Tried different Schedulers, but with no success. Added stacktrace from onError.

```
private void pullLocation(){

    myLocationService.getLocation()
            .flatMapSingle(new Function<Location, Single<DistanceResponseModel>>() {
                @Override
                public Single<DistanceResponseModel> apply(@NonNull Location location) throws Exception {
                    return distanceRepository.distanceResponseAPI(location.getLatitude() + "," + location.getLongitude(), getDestinations(), "my_google_api_key");
                }
            })

            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<DistanceResponseModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Subscription s) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onSubscribe in DistanceViewModel called. ");
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(DistanceResponseModel distanceResponseModel) {
            distanceLiveData.postValue(distanceResponseModel);
            Log.d(TAG, "onNext in DistanceViewModel called. ");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable t) {
            Log.e("YOUR_APP_LOG_TAG", "I got an error:", t);
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
            Log.d(TAG, "onComplete in DistanceViewModel called. ");
        }
    });
}
```

EDIT:

added detailed stacktrace with error code:

```
E/YOUR_APP_LOG_TAG: I got an error
    android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
        at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1450)
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:102)
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:90)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:787)
        at okhttp3.Dns.lambda$static$0(Dns.java:39)
        at okhttp3.-$$Lambda$Dns$9evC3uO-H_z08sS9O-4-hLhZ8es.lookup(Unknown Source:0)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:171)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:135)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:84)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection(ExchangeFinder.java:187)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection(ExchangeFinder.java:108)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find(ExchangeFinder.java:88)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.Transmitter.newExchange(Transmitter.java:169)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:41)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
        at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:94)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:88)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:229)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:81)
        at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:204)
        at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.CallExecuteObservable.subscribeActual(CallExecuteObservable.java:46)
        at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:12030)
        at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.BodyObservable.subscribeActual(BodyObservable.java:35)
        at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:12030)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSingleSingle.subscribeActual(ObservableSingleSingle.java:35)
        at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:3394)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFlatMapSingle$FlatMapSingleSubscriber.onNext(FlowableFlatMapSingle.java:132)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableHide$HideSubscriber.onNext(FlowableHide.java:68)
        at io.reactivex.processors.PublishProcessor$PublishSubscription.onNext(PublishProcessor.java:361)
        at io.reactivex.processors.PublishProcessor.onNext(PublishProcessor.java:244)
        at com.example.compass.viewModels.MyLocationServiceClass$1.onLocationChanged(MyLocationServiceClass.java:35)
        at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport._handleMessage(LocationManager.java:292)
        at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.-wrap0(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.handleMessage(LocationManager.java:237)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

This where I get location:

```
public class MyLocationServiceClass implements MyLocationService {

    PublishProcessor<Location> stream = PublishProcessor.create();
    LocationListener listener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(@NonNull Location location) {
            stream.onNext(location);
            Log.d(TAG, "onLocationChanged: stream.onNext(location) called");
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(@NonNull String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(@NonNull String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }
    };

    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private boolean flag;
    private Context context;

    public MyLocationServiceClass(Context context, LocationManager locationManager, boolean flag) {
        this.context = context;
        this.locationManager = locationManager;
        this.flag = flag;

    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
    void onStart() {
        if (flag) {
            start();
        }
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
    void onStop() {
        locationManager.removeUpdates(listener);
    }


    @Override
    public Flowable<Location> getLocation() {
        return stream.hide();
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        long minTimeMs = 10000;
        float minDistanceM = 5.5F;


        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            return;
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "start(): requestLocationUpdates called.");
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, minTimeMs, minDistanceM, listener);

    }

    @Override
    public void updatePermission(boolean newState) {
        flag = newState;
    }

public interface MyLocationService extends LifecycleObserver {

    Flowable<Location> getLocation();

    void start();
    void updatePermission(boolean newState);
}
```

Any idea what could it be? Let me know if you want more details. Hope this will help.

repo with whole code: https://github.com/LightingTT/Compass

Comment: Could you please post the stacktrace?

Comment: Well, my code compiles, so there are no errors. However, when I logd onError, there is NetworkOnMainThreadException thrown. Not sure if pasting whole log will be usefull.

Comment: It would be interesting to see where the exception is being thrown. Log the stacktrace and not just the name of the exception. While there, you could also include key parts of `getLocation()`.

Comment: Question updated with stacktrace.

Comment: Could you please append the logic from `myLocationService.getLocation()` ? SubscribeOn will call the subscribeActual on given Thread. You see in your stacktrace, that the Looper emits the value. Therefore everything after `MyLocationServiceClass$1.onLocationChanged` will be emitted on the Main-Looper. If you have some operator after this, which does some Networking, you will get this error. Do you have a `single(defaultvalue : T)` or `singleOrError(..)` somewhere? I see it in the stacktrace somewhere in the middle.

Comment: I'm using Single for api call in pullLocation(). Is that what you mean?

Comment: Try `distanceRepository.distanceResponseAPI(...).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` directly. Applying it after `flatMap` does not affect the lambda inside in your setup.

Comment: @akarnokd, god damn it. I am too late. Yes, it seems the flatMapSingle is the root-cause of the issue (e.g. stacktrace: `flowable.FlowableFlatMapSingle`). I would suggest the same, as @akarnokd suggested. If you this works, I will write an answer why this is, like it is.

Comment: What do you mean directly? I'm little confused

Comment: As @akarnokd already mentioned, you should try it like this: https://gist.github.com/SergejIsbrecht/07ff3e008a2afb5cdd479b25ada80e77

Comment: Error gone, thank you very much. However, onNext is still not called.

Comment: And would appreciate oficial answer with some details, thanks!

Comment: @PiotrZaremba, you most likely do not get a value back from `distanceRepository.distanceResponseAPI`. Try mocking the repository with a default value and check again. If it works, it might be, that the http requests somehow does not return.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Problem

An onError (NetworkOnMainThreadException) is propagated to the subscriber, when calling `distanceRepository.distanceResponseAPI(location.getLatitude() + "," + location.getLongitude(), getDestinations(), "my_google_api_key")`.

### Why is an exception thrown?

Doing network requests on the UI-Eventloop is prohibited, in order not to block the UI.

### Why does subscribeOn not help?

`subscribeOn` calls the subscribeActual method of a operator upstream on given Scheduler. In your case subscribe for `flatMapSingle` operator is called from a worker-thread in the IO-Scheduler. `flatMapSingle` calls `myLocationService.getLocation()` on the same thread.

As you can see in the stacktrace, the onNext from source-observable, which is returned from `getLocation`, is emitted from the UI-thread

```
    at io.reactivex.processors.PublishProcessor$PublishSubscription.onNext(PublishProcessor.java:361)
    at io.reactivex.processors.PublishProcessor.onNext(PublishProcessor.java:244)
    at com.example.compass.viewModels.MyLocationServiceClass$1.onLocationChanged(MyLocationServiceClass.java:35)
    at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport._handleMessage(LocationManager.java:292)
    at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.-wrap0(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.handleMessage(LocationManager.java:237)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
```

The value is emitted via onNext on the calling-thread (UI-Thread), because the callback is called from the UI-thread. The `flatMapSingle` operator is also called on the calling UI-thread. It subscribes to the returned `Single` from the lambda and subscribes to it on the calling thread. Therefore the UI-thread invokes the network-request on the UI-thread and the exception is thrown by the Android runtime. `SubscribeOn` does not make sure, that onNext is downstream on given `Scheduler`. It only makes sure, that the subscription happens in this thread. In your case, your source-observable will get notified by the Android runtime on the UI-Thread.

### Solution?

Use `observeOn` right after `myLocationService.getLocation()` in order to switch the thread from one operator to another. `observeOn` makes sure, that the `onNext` call downstream happens on given scheduler. Therefore the subscription to the inner stream in `flatMapSingle` would happen on given scheduler worker-thread and not the ui-thread. You could also apply `subscribeOn` on the `Single` in `flatMapSingle`. This would make sure, that the network-call would happen on given scheduler worker-thread.

```
        .flatMapSingle(new Function<Location, Single<DistanceResponseModel>>() {
            @Override
            public Single<DistanceResponseModel> apply(@NonNull Location location) throws Exception {
                return distanceRepository.distanceResponseAPI(location.getLatitude() + "," + location.getLongitude(), getDestinations(), "my_google_api_key")
                                         .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
            }
        })
```

### Further reading

http://tomstechnicalblog.blogspot.com/2016/02/rxjava-understanding-observeon-and.html?m=1